# Does worklight iFix require any upgrade on worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Recently to support iOS 8, IBM Worklight team has released iFix, What i understand is this iFix is applicable at Xcode level, Is it required to upgrade something on the Worklight server level to make it comaptible after the Apps are released. Please suggest.

Link :- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684538

Thanks
djrekcer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 8 related fixes are all in the client-side, meaning Worklight Studio-only (not Xcode... you use Xcode only *after* re-building the Worklight project in Eclipse). There are no Worklight Server-related fixes for iOS 8 support.

The only server-related fixes are if you are using Application Center, which will require updating the server component as well (because it serves Dojo-based pages), in addition to the client application (which uses Dojo as well). Dojo support for iOS 8 was added in this iFix.

Comment: Thanks Idan for your quick reply

Comment: I am using Ant and Grunt for build automation. And from links I see that worklight-ant.jar and worklight-jee-library.jar are available as part of Server component of iFix patch. Hence please let me know why Worklight iFix doesn't require server update?

Comment: Note that I am using Worklight 6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 for development server. <br> And I am worried about Worklight Direct Update feature.

Comment: There is no such distinction. Get the latest. Explain your worrying.